# Facebook Graph API create_event error password parameter required

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create an event from my Django app using the Facebook Graph API (via the python-sdk). I'm using the http://github.com/mscheibe/python-sdk fork, which is all good. I log my user in, get and store the access token etc.

The problem is when I go to push the new event up I'm getting this error message back: "Graph API Error: (#100) The parameter password is required".

I've gone through the docs, and googled all over, but just can't see why I'm getting this particular error back. The json data I'm sending through to the facebook-python-sdk as far as I can see is formatted fine and with the correct parameters. I'm calling put_event and passing through the user's id and the following:

{"name": "My Event Name", "privacy": "OPEN", "access_token": "231983993485023|2.AQDK5NtlBTkm........", "start_time": "2011-05-02", "description": "A long description goes in here", "end_time": "2011-07-09", "location": "The Frontier"}

Pretty standard I would have thought. Am I missing something?!

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, right the error message I was getting back was misleading me. What was actually happening was a error in a loop in my form. It was converting my entire dictionary output into a json string, rather than the individual parameters (if necessary) in the dictionary.

So thats easily fixed! Now I'm only using json to convert a parameter if required and passing a well formed dictionary through to the various facebook-python-sdk methods. All is working great!